TilePanel for Avalonia, `DependencyProperty` to `AvaloniaProperty`
I want a WrapPanel for Avalonia that wraps its content by placing the items next to each other, without spacing, just like in this article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/482501/TilePanel-An-alternative-to-the-WrapPanel
Like so 
I'm trying to convert the code from WPF to Avalonia equivalent. Problem is that I'm struggling with how to code the DependencyProperty to AvaloniaProperty
Original code for WPF Control:
public class TilePanel : Panel
{
    public enum OrientationCategories
    {
        Vertical = 0,
        Horizontal = 1,
    }
    
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OrientationProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Orientation", typeof(OrientationCategories), typeof(TilePanel), new PropertyMetadata(OrientationCategories.Vertical, OnOrientationChanged));

    public OrientationCategories Orientation  // here I get an error "Expected class, delegate, enum, interface or struct"
        {
            get { return (OrientationCategories)GetValue(OrientationProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(OrientationProperty, value);
            }
        }

    private static void OnOrientationChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Panel)d).InvalidateMeasure();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AlignmentBoundaryProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("AlignmentBoundary", typeof(double), typeof(TilePanel), new PropertyMetadata(0.0, OnAlignmentBoundaryChanged));

    public double AlignmentBoundary
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(AlignmentBoundaryProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(AlignmentBoundaryProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private static void OnAlignmentBoundaryChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Panel)d).InvalidateMeasure();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AlignOnLesserEdgeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("AlignOnLesserEdge", typeof(bool), typeof(TilePanel), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnAlignOnLesserEdgeChanged));

    public bool AlignOnLesserEdge  // here I get an error "Expected class, delegate, enum, interface or struct"
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(AlignOnLesserEdgeProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(AlignOnLesserEdgeProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private static void OnAlignOnLesserEdgeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Panel)d).InvalidateMeasure();
    }

    /// <summary> A utility class used to tile blocks into a vertical stack of blocks. </summary>
    private class SpaceManager
    {
        private enum CompareActions
        {
            None,
            Delete,
            Split
        }

        /// <summary> Edge item - an item that defines a level at which a new item can be added. </summary>
        private class EdgeItem
        {
            /// <summary> Constructor. </summary>
            /// <param name="edgePosition1">  The left body (or top body if transposed). </param>
            /// <param name="edgePosition2"> The right body (or bottom body if transposed). </param>
            /// <param name="level">     The level. </param>
            /// <param name="edgeLimit1">  The left wing  (or top wing if transposed). </param>
            /// <param name="edgeLimit2"> The right wing  (or bottom body if transposed). </param>
            public EdgeItem(double edgePosition1, double edgePosition2, double level, double edgeLimit1, double edgeLimit2)
            {
                Level = level;
                EdgePosition1 = edgePosition1;
                EdgePosition2 = edgePosition2;
                EdgeLimit1 = edgeLimit1;
                EdgeLimit2 = edgeLimit2;
            }

            /// <summary> Copy constructor. </summary>
            /// <param name="item"> The item. </param>
            public EdgeItem(EdgeItem item)
            {
                Copy(item);
            }

            /// <summary> Copies the given item. </summary>
            /// <param name="item"> The item. </param>
            public void Copy(EdgeItem item)
            {
                Level = item.Level;
                EdgePosition1 = item.EdgePosition1;
                EdgePosition2 = item.EdgePosition2;
                EdgeLimit1 = item.EdgeLimit1;
                EdgeLimit2 = item.EdgeLimit2;
            }

            /// <summary> Compare and adjust this item with a higher level item. </summary>
            /// <param name="item"> The item to compare against. </param>
            /// <returns> true if this item can be removed otherwise false. </returns>
            public CompareActions CompareAndAdjustBody(EdgeItem item)
            {
                if (item.Level < Level)
                {
                    // item has a lower level so we don't need to adjust
                    return CompareActions.None;
                }
                if((item.EdgePosition2 < EdgePosition1) || (item.EdgePosition1 > EdgePosition2))
                {
                    // No overlap
                    return CompareActions.None;
                }
                if ((item.EdgePosition2 >= EdgePosition2) && (item.EdgePosition1 <= EdgePosition1))
                {
                    // completely overlapped
                    return CompareActions.Delete;
                }
                // partially overlapped so reduce size to only non overlapped
                if((EdgePosition1 < item.EdgePosition1) && (EdgePosition2 > item.EdgePosition2))
                {
                    return CompareActions.Split;
                }
                if (EdgePosition1 < item.EdgePosition1)
                {
                    EdgePosition2 = item.EdgePosition1;
                }
                else
                {
                    EdgePosition1 = item.EdgePosition2;
                }
                // if size is too small, mark it for delete
                return (EdgePosition2 - EdgePosition1 < 0) ? CompareActions.Delete : CompareActions.None;
            }

            /// <summary> Compare and adjust this item with a higher level item. </summary>
            /// <param name="item"> The item to compare against. </param>
            /// <returns> true if this item can be removed otherwise false. </returns>
            public void CompareAndAdjustWing(EdgeItem item)
            {
                if (item.Level <= Level)
                {
                    // item has a lower level so we don't need to adjust
                    return;
                }
                if ((item.EdgePosition2 < EdgeLimit1) || (item.EdgePosition1 > EdgeLimit2))
                {
                    // No overlap
                    return;
                }
                if ((item.EdgePosition2 >= EdgeLimit2) && (item.EdgePosition1 <= EdgeLimit1))
                {
                    // completely overlapped
                    Debug.Assert(false, "This Item should have been deleted already");
                    return;
                }
                // partially overlapped so reduce size to only non overlapped
                if ((EdgeLimit1 < item.EdgePosition1) && (EdgeLimit2 > item.EdgePosition2))
                {
                    if(EdgePosition1 > item.EdgePosition1)
                    {
                        EdgeLimit1 = item.EdgePosition2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        EdgeLimit2 = item.EdgePosition1;
                    }
                    return;
                }
                if (EdgeLimit1 < item.EdgePosition1)
                {
                    EdgeLimit2 = item.EdgePosition1;
                }
                else
                {
                    EdgeLimit1 = item.EdgePosition2;
                }
            }

            /// <summary> Determine if we can be with the supplied item. </summary>
            /// <param name="edgeItem">          The edge item to be merged with. </param>
            /// <param name="alignBoundary">     The align boundary. </param>
            /// <param name="alignOnLesserEdge"> true to align on lesser edge. </param>
            /// <returns> true if we can be merged, false if not. </returns>
            public bool CanBeMerged(EdgeItem edgeItem, double alignBoundary, bool alignOnLesserEdge)
            {
                if ((Level - edgeItem.Level > 0) && (Level - edgeItem.Level < alignBoundary))
                {
                    return ((edgeItem.EdgeLimit1 >= EdgeLimit1) && (edgeItem.EdgeLimit1 <= EdgeLimit2)) && ((edgeItem.EdgeLimit2 >= EdgeLimit1) && (edgeItem.EdgeLimit2 <= EdgeLimit2) &&
                        ((alignOnLesserEdge) || (EdgePosition1 < edgeItem.EdgePosition2)));
                }
                return false;
            }

            /// <summary> Gets or sets the vertical edge level. </summary>
            /// <value> The level. </value>
            public double Level { get; set; }

            /// <summary> Gets or sets the right body (or bottom body if transposed). </summary>
            /// <value> The right body  (or bottom body if transposed). </value>
            public double EdgePosition2 { get; set; }

            /// <summary> Gets or sets the left (or top body if transposed). </summary>
            /// <value> The left (or top body if transposed). </value>
            public double EdgePosition1 { get; set; }

            /// <summary> Gets or sets the right (or bottom wing if transposed). </summary>
            /// <value> The right  (or bottom wing if transposed). </value>
            public double EdgeLimit2 { get; set; }

            /// <summary> Gets or sets the left  (or top wing if transposed). </summary>
            /// <value> The left  (or top wing if transposed). </value>
            public double EdgeLimit1 { get; set; }

            /// <summary> Fit rectangle the rectangle into the edge space. </summary>
            /// <param name="blockWidth"> the width of the block to be fitted. </param>
            /// <param name="transposed"> true if transposed. </param>
            /// <returns> returns the top left position if fitted else null. </returns>
            public Point? FitBlock(double blockWidth, bool transposed)
            {
                if (blockWidth <= EdgeLimit2 - EdgeLimit1)
                {
                    return transposed ? new Point(Level, EdgeLimit1) : new Point(EdgeLimit1, Level);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        /// <summary> Gets or sets the align limit. </summary>
        /// <value> The align limit. </value>
        public double AlignLimit { get; set; }

        /// <summary> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the align on lesser edge. </summary>
        /// <value> true if align on lesser edge, false if not. </value>
        public bool AlignOnLesserEdge { get; set; }

        /// <summary> The left stack position. </summary>
        private readonly double _areaLimit1;
        /// <summary> The right stack position. </summary>
        private readonly double _areaLimit2;
        /// <summary> The top stack position. </summary>
        private readonly double _minAreaLevel;

        /// <summary> true if transposed (Horizontal) else (Vertical). </summary>
        private readonly bool _transposed;

        /// <summary> List of linked block rectangles. </summary>
        private readonly LinkedList<Rect> _linkedList = new LinkedList<Rect>();
        /// <summary> List of edge items. </summary>
        private List<EdgeItem> _edgeItemList;
        /// <summary> Collection of edge items. </summary>
        private LinkedList<EdgeItem> _edgeItemCollection;

        /// <summary> Constructor. </summary>
        /// <param name="areaLimit2">   The right edge of the area (or bottom edge if transposed). </param>
        /// <param name="transposed">   true if transposed. </param>
        /// <param name="minAreaLevel"> (optional) the top edge of the area (or left edge if transposed). </param>
        /// <param name="areaLimit1">   (optional) the left edge of the area (or top edge if transposed. </param>
        public SpaceManager(double areaLimit2, bool transposed=false, double minAreaLevel=0, double areaLimit1=0)
        {
            _transposed = transposed;
            _areaLimit1 = areaLimit1;
            _areaLimit2 = areaLimit2;
            _minAreaLevel = minAreaLevel;
        }

        /// <summary> Check for overlap. </summary>
        /// <param name="index"> Zero-based index of the. </param>
        /// <param name="edges"> The edges. </param>
        /// <returns> true if it succeeds, false if it fails. </returns>
        private CompareActions CheckForOverlap(LinkedListNode<EdgeItem> index, List<EdgeItem> edges)
        {
            // compare the current item to the following items (should be greater level)
            LinkedListNode<EdgeItem> subIndex = index.Next;
            while(subIndex != null)
            {
                switch(index.Value.CompareAndAdjustBody(subIndex.Value))
                {
                    // item is no longer neede so request it be deleted
                    case CompareActions.Delete:
                        return CompareActions.Delete;
                    // item needs to be split into 2 items
                    case CompareActions.Split:
                        // compare split item sizes
                        double w1 = subIndex.Value.EdgePosition1 - index.Value.EdgePosition1;
                        double w2 = index.Value.EdgePosition2 - subIndex.Value.EdgePosition2;
                        if((w1 < 0) && (w2 < 0))
                        {
                            // both too small, so delete item instead
                            return CompareActions.Delete;
                        }
                        if(w1 < 0)
                        {
                            // ignore w1 and use only w2
                            index.Value.EdgePosition1 = subIndex.Value.EdgePosition2;
                        }
                        else if(w2 < 0)
                        {
                            // ignore w2 and use only w1
                            index.Value.EdgePosition2 = subIndex.Value.EdgePosition1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // shortened w1 and insert new w2
                            EdgeItem newItem = new EdgeItem(subIndex.Value.EdgePosition2, index.Value.EdgePosition2, index.Value.Level, _areaLimit1, _areaLimit2);
                            index.Value.EdgePosition2 = subIndex.Value.EdgePosition1;
                            index.List.AddAfter(index, newItem);
                            int idx = edges.FindIndex(edge => index.Value == edge);
                            edges.Insert(idx + 1, newItem);
                        }
                        break;
                }
                subIndex = subIndex.Next;
            }
            return CompareActions.None;
        }

        /// <summary> Expand size of the edge to it's nax size. </summary>
        /// <param name="index"> Zero-based index of the. </param>
        private void GetExpandedEdgeItem(LinkedListNode<EdgeItem> index)
        {
            LinkedListNode<EdgeItem> subIndex = index.Next;
            while (subIndex != null)
            {
                index.Value.CompareAndAdjustWing(subIndex.Value);
                subIndex = subIndex.Next;
            }
            subIndex = index.Previous;
            while (subIndex != null)
            {
                index.Value.CompareAndAdjustWing(subIndex.Value);
                subIndex = subIndex.Previous;
            }
        }

        /// <summary> Adds an edge to the edge list and recalculates edge collection. </summary>
        /// <param name="rect"> The rectangle. </param>
        private void AddEdgeToCollection(Rect rect)
        {
            _linkedList.AddLast(rect);
            if (_edgeItemList == null)
            {
                _edgeItemList = new List<EdgeItem>();
                _edgeItemList.Add(new EdgeItem(_areaLimit1, _areaLimit2, _minAreaLevel, _areaLimit1, _areaLimit2));
            }
            _edgeItemList.Add(_transposed ? new EdgeItem(rect.Top, rect.Bottom, rect.Right, _areaLimit1, _areaLimit2) : new EdgeItem(rect.Left, rect.Right, rect.Bottom, _areaLimit1, _areaLimit2));
            _edgeItemList = _edgeItemList.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(r => r.Level).ToList();

            // adjust item sizes if overlapped by item with greater edge, removing items that are too small or completely overlapped
            _edgeItemCollection = new LinkedList<EdgeItem>(_edgeItemList);
            LinkedListNode<EdgeItem> index = _edgeItemCollection.First;
            while (index != null)
            {
                if (CheckForOverlap(index, _edgeItemList) == CompareActions.Delete)
                {
                    _edgeItemList.Remove(index.Value);
                }
                index = index.Next;
            }

            // calculate extents of each edge
            _edgeItemCollection = new LinkedList<EdgeItem>(_edgeItemList);
            index = _edgeItemCollection.First;
            while (index != null)
            {
                GetExpandedEdgeItem(index);
                index = index.Next;
            }

            // level off close edges
            index = _edgeItemCollection.First;
            while ((index != null)/* && (index.Next != null)*/)
            {
                List<EdgeItem> closeItems = _edgeItemCollection.Where(edge => index.Value.CanBeMerged(edge, AlignLimit, AlignOnLesserEdge)).ToList();
                foreach (var closeItem in closeItems)
                {
                    closeItem.Level = index.Value.Level;
                    closeItem.EdgeLimit1 = _areaLimit1;
                    closeItem.EdgeLimit2 = _areaLimit2;
                    var closeIndex = index.List.Find(closeItem);
                    GetExpandedEdgeItem(closeIndex);
                }
                index = index.Next;
            }
        }

        /// <summary> Inserts an edge described by size. </summary>
        /// <param name="size"> The size. </param>
        /// <returns> . </returns>
        public Point InsertEdge(Size size)
        {
            Rect r;
            // handle first element
            if (_linkedList.Count == 0)
            {
                _edgeItemList = null;
                _edgeItemCollection = null;
                r = _transposed ? new Rect(new Point(_minAreaLevel, _areaLimit1), size) : new Rect(new Point(_areaLimit1, _minAreaLevel), size);
                AddEdgeToCollection(r);
                return r.TopLeft;
            }
            LinkedListNode<EdgeItem> index = _edgeItemCollection.First;
            while (index != null)
            {
                Point? pt = _transposed ? index.Value.FitBlock(size.Height, true) : index.Value.FitBlock(size.Width, false);
                if (pt.HasValue)
                {
                    AddEdgeToCollection(new Rect(pt.Value, size));
                    return pt.Value;
                }
                index = index.Next;
            }
            Size sz = BoundingArea();
            r = _transposed ? new Rect(new Point(sz.Width + _minAreaLevel, _areaLimit1), size) : new Rect(new Point(_areaLimit1, sz.Height + _minAreaLevel), size);
            AddEdgeToCollection(r);
            return r.TopLeft;
        }

        public Size BoundingArea()
        {
            if(_linkedList.Count == 0)
            {
                if(_transposed)
                {
                    return new Size(_minAreaLevel, _areaLimit1);
                }
                return new Size(_areaLimit1, _minAreaLevel);
            }
            double right = _linkedList.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Right).Max();
            double bottom = _linkedList.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Bottom).Max();
            if (_transposed)
            {
                return new Size(right - _minAreaLevel, bottom - _areaLimit1);
            }
            return new Size(right - _areaLimit1, bottom - _minAreaLevel);
        }
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        SpaceManager spaceManager = (Orientation == OrientationCategories.Vertical) ? new SpaceManager(finalSize.Width, false) : new SpaceManager(finalSize.Height, true);
        spaceManager.AlignLimit = AlignmentBoundary;
        spaceManager.AlignOnLesserEdge = AlignOnLesserEdge;

        foreach (UIElement child in Children)
        {
            Point point = spaceManager.InsertEdge(child.DesiredSize);
            child.Arrange(new Rect(point.X, point.Y, child.DesiredSize.Width, child.DesiredSize.Height));
        }
        return spaceManager.BoundingArea();
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        SpaceManager spaceManager = (Orientation == OrientationCategories.Vertical) ? new SpaceManager(availableSize.Width, false) : new SpaceManager(availableSize.Height, true);
        spaceManager.AlignLimit = AlignmentBoundary;
        spaceManager.AlignOnLesserEdge = AlignOnLesserEdge;

        foreach (UIElement child in Children)
        {
            child.Measure(availableSize);
            spaceManager.InsertEdge(child.DesiredSize);
        }
        Size size = spaceManager.BoundingArea();
        return new Size(double.IsPositiveInfinity(availableSize.Width) ? size.Width : availableSize.Width, double.IsPositiveInfinity(availableSize.Height) ? size.Height : availableSize.Height);
    }

}

My attempt so far:
Changed the UIElements to Controls and the DependencyProperty to AvaloniaProperty but I don't understand DependencyProperty nor AvaloniaProperty well enough to figure out how to convert it

https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/0.10.x/wpf-developer-tips/dependencyproperty

@ASh that's the old 0.10 doc, better link the one from the 11.0.x versions https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/guides/custom-controls/defining-properties

To replace dependency properties with styled the main difference is that instead of passing that static method callback to the Register method like in WPF, in Avalonia you bind it by calling AddClassHandler. Alternatively you can use instance methods instead of static methods and bind to your control isntance with GetObservable. See here: https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/guides/data-binding/binding-from-code

I've kind of figured it out. It seems to work, though it has an awfully terribly sluggish performance, that makess it useless. It works, though I'd be happy if anyone wanted to give me some pointers as to why it is so slow.
public class TilePanel : Panel
{
    public TilePanel()
    {
        AffectsMeasure<TilePanel>(OrientationProperty);
        AffectsMeasure<TilePanel>(AlignmentBoundaryProperty);
        AffectsMeasure<TilePanel>(AlignOnLesserEdgeProperty);
    }
    public enum OrientationCategories
    {
        Vertical = 0,
        Horizontal = 1,
    }
    
    public static readonly StyledProperty<Orientation> OrientationProperty = 
        AvaloniaProperty.Register<TilePanel, Orientation>(nameof(Orientation));

    public OrientationCategories Orientation
    {
        get { return (OrientationCategories)GetValue(OrientationProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(OrientationProperty, value);
        }
    }
    
    public static readonly StyledProperty<double> AlignmentBoundaryProperty =
        AvaloniaProperty.Register<TilePanel, double>(nameof(AlignmentBoundaryProperty));

    public double AlignmentBoundary
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(AlignmentBoundaryProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(AlignmentBoundaryProperty, value);
        }
    }
    public static readonly StyledProperty<bool> AlignOnLesserEdgeProperty =
        AvaloniaProperty.Register<TilePanel, bool>(nameof(AlignOnLesserEdgeProperty));

    public bool AlignOnLesserEdge  // here I get an error "Expected class, delegate, enum, interface or struct"
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(AlignOnLesserEdgeProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(AlignOnLesserEdgeProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private static void OnAlignOnLesserEdgeChanged(AvaloniaProperty d, AvaloniaPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //((Panel)d).InvalidateMeasure();
    }

    /// <summary> A utility class used to tile blocks into a vertical stack of blocks. </summary>
    private class SpaceManager
    {
        private enum CompareActions
        {
            None,
            Delete,
            Split
        }

        /// <summary> Edge item - an item that defines a level at which a new item can be added. </summary>
        private class EdgeItem
        {
            /// <summary> Constructor. </summary>
            /// <param name="edgePosition1">  The left body (or top body if transposed). </param>
            /// <param name="edgePosition2"> The right body (or bottom body if transposed). </param>
            /// <param name="level">     The level. </param>
            /// <param name="edgeLimit1">  The left wing  (or top wing if transposed). </param>
            /// <param name="edgeLimit2"> The right wing  (or bottom body if transposed). </param>
            public EdgeItem(double edgePosition1, double edgePosition2, double level, double edgeLimit1, double edgeLimit2)
            {
                Level = level;
                EdgePosition1 = edgePosition1;
                EdgePosition2 = edgePosition2;
                EdgeLimit1 = edgeLimit1;
                EdgeLimit2 = edgeLimit2;
            }

            /// <summary> Copy constructor. </summary>
            /// <param name="item"> The item. </param>
            public EdgeItem(EdgeItem item)
            {
                Copy(item);
            }

            /// <summary> Copies the given item. </summary>
            /// <param name="item"> The item. </param>
            public void Copy(EdgeItem item)
            {
                Level = item.Level;
                EdgePosition1 = item.EdgePosition1;
                EdgePosition2 = item.EdgePosition2;
                EdgeLimit1 = item.EdgeLimit1;
                EdgeLimit2 = item.EdgeLimit2;
            }

            /// <summary> Compare and adjust this item with a higher level item. </summary>
            /// <param name="item"> The item to compare against. </param>
            /// <returns> true if this item can be removed otherwise false. </returns>
            public CompareActions CompareAndAdjustBody(EdgeItem item)
            {
                if (item.Level < Level)
                {
                    // item has a lower level so we don't need to adjust
                    return CompareActions.None;
                }
                if(item.EdgePosition2 < EdgePosition1 || item.EdgePosition1 > EdgePosition2)
                {
                    // No overlap
                    return CompareActions.None;
                }
                if (item.EdgePosition2 >= EdgePosition2 && item.EdgePosition1 <= EdgePosition1)
                {
                    // completely overlapped
                    return CompareActions.Delete;
                }
                // partially overlapped so reduce size to only non overlapped
                if(EdgePosition1 < item.EdgePosition1 && EdgePosition2 > item.EdgePosition2)
                {
                    return CompareActions.Split;
                }
                if (EdgePosition1 < item.EdgePosition1)
                {
                    EdgePosition2 = item.EdgePosition1;
                }
                else
                {
                    EdgePosition1 = item.EdgePosition2;
                }
                // if size is too small, mark it for delete
                return EdgePosition2 - EdgePosition1 < 0 ? CompareActions.Delete : CompareActions.None;
            }

            /// <summary> Compare and adjust this item with a higher level item. </summary>
            /// <param name="item"> The item to compare against. </param>
            /// <returns> true if this item can be removed otherwise false. </returns>
            public void CompareAndAdjustWing(EdgeItem item)
            {
                if (item.Level <= Level)
                {
                    // item has a lower level so we don't need to adjust
                    return;
                }
                if (item.EdgePosition2 < EdgeLimit1 || item.EdgePosition1 > EdgeLimit2)
                {
                    // No overlap
                    return;
                }
                if (item.EdgePosition2 >= EdgeLimit2 && item.EdgePosition1 <= EdgeLimit1)
                {
                    // completely overlapped
                    Debug.Assert(false, "This Item should have been deleted already");
                    return;
                }
                // partially overlapped so reduce size to only non overlapped
                if (EdgeLimit1 < item.EdgePosition1 && EdgeLimit2 > item.EdgePosition2)
                {
                    if(EdgePosition1 > item.EdgePosition1)
                    {
                        EdgeLimit1 = item.EdgePosition2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        EdgeLimit2 = item.EdgePosition1;
                    }
                    return;
                }
                if (EdgeLimit1 < item.EdgePosition1)
                {
                    EdgeLimit2 = item.EdgePosition1;
                }
                else
                {
                    EdgeLimit1 = item.EdgePosition2;
                }
            }

            /// <summary> Determine if we can be with the supplied item. </summary>
            /// <param name="edgeItem">          The edge item to be merged with. </param>
            /// <param name="alignBoundary">     The align boundary. </param>
            /// <param name="alignOnLesserEdge"> true to align on lesser edge. </param>
            /// <returns> true if we can be merged, false if not. </returns>
            public bool CanBeMerged(EdgeItem edgeItem, double alignBoundary, bool alignOnLesserEdge)
            {
                if (Level - edgeItem.Level > 0 && Level - edgeItem.Level < alignBoundary)
                {
                    return edgeItem.EdgeLimit1 >= EdgeLimit1 && edgeItem.EdgeLimit1 <= EdgeLimit2 && edgeItem.EdgeLimit2 >= EdgeLimit1 && edgeItem.EdgeLimit2 <= EdgeLimit2 &&
                           (alignOnLesserEdge || EdgePosition1 < edgeItem.EdgePosition2);
                }
                return false;
            }

            /// <summary> Gets or sets the vertical edge level. </summary>
            /// <value> The level. </value>
            public double Level { get; set; }

            /// <summary> Gets or sets the right body (or bottom body if transposed). </summary>
            /// <value> The right body  (or bottom body if transposed). </value>
            public double EdgePosition2 { get; set; }

            /// <summary> Gets or sets the left (or top body if transposed). </summary>
            /// <value> The left (or top body if transposed). </value>
            public double EdgePosition1 { get; set; }

            /// <summary> Gets or sets the right (or bottom wing if transposed). </summary>
            /// <value> The right  (or bottom wing if transposed). </value>
            public double EdgeLimit2 { get; set; }

            /// <summary> Gets or sets the left  (or top wing if transposed). </summary>
            /// <value> The left  (or top wing if transposed). </value>
            public double EdgeLimit1 { get; set; }

            /// <summary> Fit rectangle the rectangle into the edge space. </summary>
            /// <param name="blockWidth"> the width of the block to be fitted. </param>
            /// <param name="transposed"> true if transposed. </param>
            /// <returns> returns the top left position if fitted else null. </returns>
            public Point? FitBlock(double blockWidth, bool transposed)
            {
                if (blockWidth <= EdgeLimit2 - EdgeLimit1)
                {
                    return transposed ? new Point(Level, EdgeLimit1) : new Point(EdgeLimit1, Level);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        /// <summary> Gets or sets the align limit. </summary>
        /// <value> The align limit. </value>
        public double AlignLimit { get; set; }

        /// <summary> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the align on lesser edge. </summary>
        /// <value> true if align on lesser edge, false if not. </value>
        public bool AlignOnLesserEdge { get; set; }

        /// <summary> The left stack position. </summary>
        private readonly double _areaLimit1;
        /// <summary> The right stack position. </summary>
        private readonly double _areaLimit2;
        /// <summary> The top stack position. </summary>
        private readonly double _minAreaLevel;

        /// <summary> true if transposed (Horizontal) else (Vertical). </summary>
        private readonly bool _transposed;

        /// <summary> List of linked block rectangles. </summary>
        private readonly LinkedList<Rect> _linkedList = [];
        /// <summary> List of edge items. </summary>
        private List<EdgeItem>? _edgeItemList;
        /// <summary> Collection of edge items. </summary>
        private LinkedList<EdgeItem>? _edgeItemCollection;

        /// <summary> Constructor. </summary>
        /// <param name="areaLimit2">   The right edge of the area (or bottom edge if transposed). </param>
        /// <param name="transposed">   true if transposed. </param>
        /// <param name="minAreaLevel"> (optional) the top edge of the area (or left edge if transposed). </param>
        /// <param name="areaLimit1">   (optional) the left edge of the area (or top edge if transposed. </param>
        public SpaceManager(double areaLimit2, bool transposed=false, double minAreaLevel=0, double areaLimit1=0)
        {
            _transposed = transposed;
            _areaLimit1 = areaLimit1;
            _areaLimit2 = areaLimit2;
            _minAreaLevel = minAreaLevel;
        }

        /// <summary> Check for overlap. </summary>
        /// <param name="index"> Zero-based index of the. </param>
        /// <param name="edges"> The edges. </param>
        /// <returns> true if it succeeds, false if it fails. </returns>
        private CompareActions CheckForOverlap(LinkedListNode<EdgeItem> index, List<EdgeItem>? edges)
        {
            for (var subIndex = index.Next; subIndex != null; subIndex = subIndex.Next)
            {
                // ReSharper disable once SwitchStatementMissingSomeEnumCasesNoDefault
                switch (index.Value.CompareAndAdjustBody(subIndex.Value))
                {
                    case CompareActions.Delete:
                        return CompareActions.Delete;
                    case CompareActions.Split:
                        var w1 = subIndex.Value.EdgePosition1 - index.Value.EdgePosition1;
                        var w2 = index.Value.EdgePosition2 - subIndex.Value.EdgePosition2;
                        switch (w1)
                        {
                            case < 0 when w2 < 0:
                                // both too small, so delete item instead
                                return CompareActions.Delete;
                            case < 0:
                                // ignore w1 and use only w2
                                index.Value.EdgePosition1 = subIndex.Value.EdgePosition2;
                                break;
                            default:
                                if (w2 < 0)
                                {
                                    // ignore w2 and use only w1
                                    index.Value.EdgePosition2 = subIndex.Value.EdgePosition1;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    // shortened w1 and insert new w2
                                    var newItem = new EdgeItem(subIndex.Value.EdgePosition2, index.Value.EdgePosition2, index.Value.Level, _areaLimit1, _areaLimit2);
                                    index.Value.EdgePosition2 = subIndex.Value.EdgePosition1;
                                    var idx = edges.FindIndex(edge => index.Value == edge);
                                    edges.Insert(idx + 1, newItem);
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
            return CompareActions.None;
        }

        /// <summary> Expand size of the edge to it's nax size. </summary>
        /// <param name="index"> Zero-based index of the. </param>
        private void GetExpandedEdgeItem(LinkedListNode<EdgeItem> index)
        {
            var subIndex = index.Next;
            while (subIndex != null)
            {
                index.Value.CompareAndAdjustWing(subIndex.Value);
                subIndex = subIndex.Next;
            }
            subIndex = index.Previous;
            while (subIndex != null)
            {
                index.Value.CompareAndAdjustWing(subIndex.Value);
                subIndex = subIndex.Previous;
            }
        }

        /// <summary> Adds an edge to the edge list and recalculates edge collection. </summary>
        /// <param name="rect"> The rectangle. </param>
        private void AddEdgeToCollection(Rect rect)
        {
            _linkedList.AddLast(rect);
            _edgeItemList ??= // ReSharper disable once NullCoalescingConditionIsAlwaysNotNullAccordingToAPIContract
            [
                new EdgeItem(_areaLimit1, _areaLimit2, _minAreaLevel, _areaLimit1, _areaLimit2)
            ];
            _edgeItemList.Add(_transposed ? new EdgeItem(rect.Top, rect.Bottom, rect.Right, _areaLimit1, _areaLimit2) : new EdgeItem(rect.Left, rect.Right, rect.Bottom, _areaLimit1, _areaLimit2));
            //_edgeItemList.Sort((item, edgeItem) => item.EdgePosition1.CompareTo(edgeItem.EdgePosition1));
            _edgeItemList = _edgeItemList.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(r => r.Level).ToList();

            // adjust item sizes if overlapped by item with greater edge, removing items that are too small or completely overlapped
            _edgeItemCollection = new LinkedList<EdgeItem>(_edgeItemList);
            var index = _edgeItemCollection.First;
            while (index != null)
            {
                if (CheckForOverlap(index, _edgeItemList) == CompareActions.Delete)
                {
                    _edgeItemList.Remove(index.Value);
                }
                index = index.Next;
            }

            // calculate extents of each edge
            _edgeItemCollection = new LinkedList<EdgeItem>(_edgeItemList);
            index = _edgeItemCollection.First;
            while (index != null)
            {
                GetExpandedEdgeItem(index);
                index = index.Next;
            }

            // level off close edges
            index = _edgeItemCollection.First;
            while (index != null/* && (index.Next != null)*/)
            {
                var closeItems = _edgeItemCollection.Where(edge => index.Value.CanBeMerged(edge, AlignLimit, AlignOnLesserEdge)).ToList();
                foreach (var closeItem in closeItems)
                {
                    closeItem.Level = index.Value.Level;
                    closeItem.EdgeLimit1 = _areaLimit1;
                    closeItem.EdgeLimit2 = _areaLimit2;
                    var closeIndex = index.List.Find(closeItem);
                    GetExpandedEdgeItem(closeIndex);
                }
                index = index.Next;
            }
        }

        /// <summary> Inserts an edge described by size. </summary>
        /// <param name="size"> The size. </param>
        /// <returns> . </returns>
        public Point InsertEdge(Size size)
        {
            Rect r;
            // handle first element
            if (_linkedList.Count == 0)
            {
                _edgeItemList = null;
                _edgeItemCollection = null;
                r = _transposed ? new Rect(new Point(_minAreaLevel, _areaLimit1), size) : new Rect(new Point(_areaLimit1, _minAreaLevel), size);
                AddEdgeToCollection(r);
                return r.TopLeft;
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < _edgeItemCollection.Count; i++)
            {
                var pt = _transposed ?
                    _edgeItemCollection.ElementAt(i).FitBlock(size.Height, true) :
                    _edgeItemCollection.ElementAt(i).FitBlock(size.Width, false);
                if (!pt.HasValue)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                AddEdgeToCollection(new Rect(pt.Value, size));
                return pt.Value;
            }
            var sz = BoundingArea();
            r = _transposed ?
                new Rect(new Point(sz.Width + _minAreaLevel, _areaLimit1), size) :
                new Rect(new Point(_areaLimit1, sz.Height + _minAreaLevel), size);
            AddEdgeToCollection(r);
            return r.TopLeft;
        }

        public Size BoundingArea()
        {
            if(_linkedList.Count == 0)
            {
                return _transposed ?
                    new Size(_minAreaLevel, _areaLimit1) :
                    new Size(_areaLimit1, _minAreaLevel);
            }
            var right = _linkedList.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Right).Max();
            var bottom = _linkedList.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Bottom).Max();
            return _transposed ? 
                new Size(right - _minAreaLevel, bottom - _areaLimit1) :
                new Size(right - _areaLimit1, bottom - _minAreaLevel);
        }
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        var spaceManager = Orientation == OrientationCategories.Vertical ? new SpaceManager(finalSize.Width) : new SpaceManager(finalSize.Height, true);
        spaceManager.AlignLimit = AlignmentBoundary;
        spaceManager.AlignOnLesserEdge = AlignOnLesserEdge;

        foreach (var child in Children)
        {
            var point = spaceManager.InsertEdge(child.DesiredSize);
            child.Arrange(new Rect(point.X, point.Y, child.DesiredSize.Width, child.DesiredSize.Height));
        }
        return spaceManager.BoundingArea();
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        var spaceManager = Orientation == OrientationCategories.Vertical ? new SpaceManager(availableSize.Width) : new SpaceManager(availableSize.Height, true);
        spaceManager.AlignLimit = AlignmentBoundary;
        spaceManager.AlignOnLesserEdge = AlignOnLesserEdge;

        foreach (var child in Children)
        {
            child.Measure(availableSize);
            spaceManager.InsertEdge(child.DesiredSize);
        }
        var size = spaceManager.BoundingArea();
        return new Size(double.IsPositiveInfinity(availableSize.Width) ? size.Width : availableSize.Width, double.IsPositiveInfinity(availableSize.Height) ? size.Height : availableSize.Height);
    }

